# Convert letters in to numbers in SQL

Tags: sql, excel

I have to find the average of numbers in a column which includes both letters and numbers. Since the AVG() only works if the column only contains numbers I have to change the letters to numbers or change them to a blank cell. This is what I have now but does not work

```
declare Grade as integer 
cast(replace(replace(replace(grades.grade,'A',''),'B',''),'C','') as int) as cleanGrade
```

Comment: Why is your question tagged Excel?  What is the code supposed to be?  What database are you using?  Database tables don't have "cells", so what do you mean?  Sample data and desired results are also helpful.

Comment: Im sorry, I'm working in SQL through excel

Answer (score 0):

Most databases have some method of determining whether a value is numeric.  For instance, in SQL Server, you can use `try_convert()`:

```
select avg(try_convert(decimal(10, 4), grade))
```

Or in MySQL, you could use:

```
select (case when grade regexp '^[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]*$' then grade end)
```

There is similar logic for most other databases.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to map letters to numbers, say, letter grades to numeric values, you could use [`CASE ... WHEN ... THEN ... END`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) expression.

Assuming that grades are `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and `F`, you could do it as follows:

```
SELECT AVG(
    CASE Grade
        WHEN 'A' THEN 100
        WHEN 'B' THEN 90
        WHEN 'C' THEN 80
        WHEN 'D' THEN 60
        WHEN 'F' THEN 0
        ELSE CAST(Grade AS int)
    END
)
FROM Grades
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. This does not quite work Im not sure why, sql only gives me a column with 1 and 3 in it when I put all the letters to, for example 0. Do you know why?

Comment: @helena5050 You need to supply sample data and expected result, because it's not clear from your description.